# Convert stateless component using connect to container component - optimisation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have this component that uses react-redux `connect`:

```
let Vepo = (props) => (
  <Container >
    <Header style={styles.header}>
      <Left>
        <Button transparent>
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.title}>Search</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
      </Right>
    </Header>
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView >
        <Keywords />
        <Categories />
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  </Container>
)

Vepo = connect(
  null,
  null
)(Vepo)

export default Vepo
```

And I have just converted it to a container component without `connect` in order to easily use lifecycle methods:

```
class Vepo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      this.forceUpdate()
      console.log(store)
    })
    console.log(store)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <Container >
    <Header style={styles.header}>
      <Left>
        <Button transparent>
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.title}>Search</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
      </Right>
    </Header>
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView >
        <Keywords />
        <Categories />
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  </Container>
  )}
}
Vepo.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Vepo
```

However I have just seen from a SO answer that `forceUpdate()` is a hack that is unnecessary.

What do I need to do in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` to have a performant component? Is the subscribing necessary? If I only delete `this.forceUpdate()` will it then be a performant component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like you are not using `store` in the `Vepo` component. Or in the other word it's not need a container. If this is the case, just remove store from it. It's a bad practice to mix up container with a presenter. If you don't need your component be aware of redux, don't write a container for it. If it need redux store, write a separate container.

```
class VepoPresenter extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("componentWillUnmount");
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Container >
        <Header style={styles.header}>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
          <Title style={styles.title}>Search</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
          </Right>
        </Header>
        <Container style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView >
            <Keywords />
            <Categories />
          </ScrollView>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

Vepo = connect(
  null,
  null
)(VepoPresenter);

export default Vepo
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is the lifecycle method I mentioned I need?

Comment: I had updated the answer, and add them back. I removed them because  they are not  needed:).  Adding all of the store to the one component, like your code, is not a good idea.